# How to read outlook email saved under local directory on pc using javax mail api

Tags: outlook, jakarta-mail

I am trying to read email saved to my localhost directory using javax mail api but I am not sure how to read from your local directory.

So I found third pary library which reads email for me and returns data in string format but not sure how to build javax mail message using those string data.

Problem trying to solve :

```
 I want to read header from email which should be in key-value form. This comes only when you read from IMAP server.
```

Any help appreciated. 
thank you

Happy Thanksgiving!!

Comment: What third party library are you using?  What's an example of the string format data it returns?

Comment: auxilii - http://auxilii.com/msgparser/

I am able to parse outlook message with this which is stored at my local directory.

Comment: auxilii - http://auxilii.com/msgparser/

I am able to parse outlook message which is stored at my local directory with this library.

Now I need to convert that email header (string) part to key-value pair. So I can pass it to our existing code.

Comment: What sort of key/value pairs does your existing code expect?  Are you looking for a key such "Subject" with a value such as "This is the subject for the message"?  Are they stored in a Java Properties or Map object?

Comment: Yes, that is email metadata contains all subject, form and other values separated by : colon.
I am actually looking for to convert mime message to javax mail message

Comment: Now you're asking for something completely different.  If you want to convert a MIME message to a javax.mail.Message object, use the javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage constructor that takes an InputStream and supply the byte stream that is in MIME format.

Comment: Yeah looks like lot of confusion in my head, I read email using third party library which returned message in string format and now need to convert respective header , email body and message in mime message object and convert back to java mail message. This way we completed reading email from local directory.

I was looking for any way if we could read that email directly using javax mail api.

appreciate your time